# Spring core/beans 5.3.18 upgraded project won't start - Autowired and Bean annotations crashing

Tags: java, spring, autowired

here's the error:

```
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.mycompany.chassis.engine.core.web.listener.ChassisContextLoaderListener]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'chassisApiSpringConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sdpLoggingOn'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'boolean'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [false,false]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
```

so I upgraded to spring-beans 5.3.18, got the above error, thought I was slick and upgraded spring-core to match the version of spring-beans and I still get this error.

I have like 4 separate pom files, please direct me to how I can give you the best info to help me through this. Would upgrading spring-web to the same version help or is it something else entirely? It feels like Spring Beans doesn't recognize @Value anymore? Here's the line it's complaining about.

```
@Value("${sdp.logging.on:false}")
private boolean sdpLoggingOn;
```

Here's the imports I currently have:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
```

Maybe Autowired and Value aren't in the factory anymore now with the upgrade?

Comment: You should always use the same version for all Spring libraries, so yes, upgrade spring-web and all other spring-* libs to 5.3.18 as well.

Comment: I've upgraded all Spring to 5.3.18 and am still getting the error about can't convert a String to boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Add the spring framework bom to your dependencyManagement section to keep all the spring framework jars at the same version.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency> 
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId> 
                <version>${spring.version}</version> 
                <type>pom</type> 
                <scope>import</scope> 
            </dependency> 
        </dependencies> 
</dependencyManagement>
```

With multiple pom files, in my experience, it works best to have them share a common parent pom which manages the dependencies.